# How do I use a csv data as variables to apply it for a formula?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, csv, data-analysis

I'm trying to use data from a csv file ( https://www.kaggle.com/jingbinxu/sample-of-car-data ). I only need the horsepower and weight columns as variables for the equation: ( 1/4 mile et = 6.290 * (weight/hp) ** .33 ), but it won't apply it. I don't know if the storage is working or I shouldn't do it as a class. When I run the program it doesn't show any errors, but it doesn't show results either. Then I got to plot the results, but I don't think it's even calculating and storing results. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's the current code i have:

```
import numpy as np
class car_race_analysis():

    def __init__(self, filename):
        import numpy as np
        self.data = np.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter= ',', skip_header = 1 )

    def race_stats(self,w,h):
        #cars in data
        cars = np.unique(self.data[:,0])
        #storage for output
        race_times = []
        #for each car
        for car in cars:
            #mask
            mask = self.data[:,0] == car
            #get data
            w = self.data[mask,12]
            h = self.data[mask,18]
            #apply formula
            qrtr_mile = 6.290 * ( w / h ) ** .33
            race_times.append(qrtr_mile)
            #new atribute
        self.race_times = np.array(race_times)
        print(race_times)

    def trend_plotter(self):
        import matlib.pyplot as plt
        #inputs
        self.race_stats
        cars = np.unique(self.data[:,0])
        #plot
        plt.plot(cars,self.race_times)
        plt.xlabel("Car")
        plt.ylabel("1/4 Mile Time")
        plt.savefig("trend_plot.png")

filename = 'car_data.csv'
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! The code you provided doesn't show where you instantiate a `car_race_analysis` object or call any of the associated methods. If you have additional code that shows this, please [edit] it into your question. If not, then that's likely the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. I think you meant `matplotlib` instead of `matlib`. Make sure you install it `pip3 install matplotlib --user` and edit your code accordingly.
2. Your previous code wasn't working because you weren't instantiating a class or running any methods. The only "work" your program did was to define the class and then set a `filename` variable.

To solve #2, replace your `filename=...` line with the code below. 
Here's what it does:

1. It checks to see if the file is being run directly (i.e. from command prompt such as `python3 <your_file_name>.py`. If this class is being imported and used from a different python file, this code would not be executed. More reading: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-the-if-**name**-**main**-do/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-the-if-__name__-__main__-do/)
2. We instantiate a instance of your class and supply the `filename` variable since that it was your class' `__init__` method expects.
3. We invoke the `trend_plotter` method on the instance of the class.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'car_data.csv'
    car_analysis = car_race_analysis(filename)
    car_analysis.trend_plotter()
```

Even with those changes, your program will not work because it has other errors. I made a guess at fixing it, which I've pasted below, but I strongly encourage you do `diff` my changes to understand what I altered to be sure it does what you want.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class car_race_analysis():
    race_times = []
    cars = []

    def __init__(self, filename):
        import numpy as np
        self.data = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',', skip_header=1)

    def race_stats(self, w, h):
        #cars in data
        self.cars = np.unique(self.data[:, 0])
        # storage for output
        self.race_times = []
        # for each car
        for car in self.cars:
            # mask
            mask = self.data[:, 0] == car
            # get data
            w = self.data[mask, 12]
            h = self.data[mask, 18]
            # apply formula
            qrtr_mile = 6.290 * (w / h) ** .33
            self.race_times.append(qrtr_mile)
            # new atribute
        self.race_times = np.array(self.race_times)

    def trend_plotter(self):
        # inputs
        self.race_stats(len(self.cars), len(self.race_times))
        # plot
        plt.plot(self.cars, self.race_times)
        plt.xlabel("Car")
        plt.ylabel("1/4 Mile Time")
        plt.savefig("trend_plot.png")
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'car_data.csv'
    car_analysis = car_race_analysis(filename)
    car_analysis.trend_plotter()
```